# Post Web Api C#, Con mas de una entidad

Tags: json, api, web

Estoy desarrollando una api con la finalidad de recibir un post, pero el posteo de la data tiene la siguiente estructura

```
{
    "Factura":{
        "FatCodigo": 2,
        "Fatnombre": "Prueba",
        "FacturaDetalle": {
            "FatCodigo":2,
            "Fatcantidad": 22
        }
    }
}
```

el problema es que cuando se realizar el posteo en el metodo del web api los parametros recibido es son todos null como se puede ver en la imagen. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Clase Factura

```
[Table("Factura")]
public partial class Factura
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int FatCodigo { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Fatnombre { get; set; }

    public virtual FacturaDetalle FacturaDetalle { get; set; }
}
}
```

Factura Detalle

```
[Table("FacturaDetalle")] public partial class FacturaDetalle { [Key] [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] public int FatCodigo { get; set; }

    public int? Fatcantidad { get; set; }

    public virtual Factura Factura { get; set; }
}
}
```

Model

```
public partial class Model1 : DbContext
{
    public Model1()
        : base("name=entidad")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Factura> Factura { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<FacturaDetalle> FacturaDetalle { get; set; }

   

 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Factura>()
            .Property(e => e.Fatnombre)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Factura>()
            .HasOptional(e => e.FacturaDetalle)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Factura);
    }
}
}
```

Quisiera saber como puedo leer el json dentro del post

Comment: Hola, utiliza una librería llamada Newtonsoft.Json esta en nuget y lo utilizas `dataResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CLASE_BASE>(data)`, esto te puede ayudar a comprender lo que digo : https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm.

Comment: Como estas haciendo la llamada?

Comment: puedes enviar el objeto de esta manera {
        "FatCodigo": 2,
        "Fatnombre": "Prueba",
        "FacturaDetalle": {
            "FatCodigo":2,
            "Fatcantidad": 22
        }

Comment: el problema es que el json me lo van enviar tal cual lo puse en el ejemplo

Comment: bueno una solucion rapida es que crees otro objeto que tenga como unica propiedad Factura, y la otra solucion es que definas un mapeo personalizado Binding,...